# Ubuntu Failing on Boot

Tags: boot, networking, uefi, acpi

my Linux computer shut down yesterday and upon rebooting it this showed up and fails after the last line of this messaging. It was able to boot into the desktop a couple times after unplugging it for some time and then booting it up again; however, now it refuses to even run past this line of text after 15+ times of manipulating bios settings and different booting patterns.

The CMOS was reset after a cmos hp 502 error showed up. It will occasionally do this if the pc is reset 3-5 times repetitively.

Additionally, I have tried to get into the GRUB menu since other suggestions have pointed towards this and it will not allow me even if the shift button is held or other buttons like esc. If anyone has any suggestions or advice, it would be much appreciated.

```
[0.538672] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Could not resolve symbol, AE_NOT_FOUND 

[0.538682] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog

[o.538686] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Could not resolve symbol, AE_NOT_FOUND 

[0.538688] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog

[0.539920] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Could not resolve symbol, AE_NOT_FOUND

[0.539923] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog

[0.810499] blacklist: Problem Blacklisting hash (-13)

[0.810499] blacklist: Problem Blacklisting hash (-13)

[0.810499] blacklist: Problem Blacklisting hash (-13)

[0.810499] blacklist: Problem Blacklisting hash (-13)

[0.810499] blacklist: Problem Blacklisting hash (-13)

[0.810499] blacklist: Problem Blacklisting hash (-13)

/dev/nvmeOn1p2: recovering journal 
/dev/nvmeOn1p2: clean
```

Comment: Issue was found to be with the kernel 6.2. Revering back seemed to fix it.